# how to pass function to ajax plugin parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this jquery ajax plugin :

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.Ajax_Data = function (Controller, Action, Data, onsuccess, onerror) {
    event.preventDefault();

        var options = {};
        options.url = "/" + Controller + "/" + Action;
        options.type = "POST";
        options.data = JSON.stringify(Data);
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json";
        options.success = onsuccess;
        options.error = onerror;

        $.ajax(options);
};
})(jQuery);
```

the question is : i need to pass function to parameters onsuccess and onerror

to be something like the following

```
 $(this).Ajax_Data("Employee", "Delete", { Id: CurrantID },
                function () {
                    // onsuccess remove tr
                    $('tr:eq(' + RowIndex + ')').remove();
                },
                function () {
                    // onerror show message
                    alert('there is some thing wrong !!');
                });
```

Comment: so whats the problem, your code is correct there.

Comment: the function have not been executed

Comment: the row on sql server was deleted successfully but tr not removed

Comment: add data field as parameter in callbacks

Comment: you missed to get RowIndex from response add the "data" as parameter to callback and the use data.RowIndex

Answer (score 0):

i was found a good solving

it's the following

```
function onsuccess() { $('tr:eq(' + RowIndex + ')').remove(); };
function onerror() { alert('there is some thing wrong !!'); };

$(this).Ajax_Data("OnePageGrid", "Delete", { Id: CurrantID }, 
                 onsuccess(),
                 onerror());
```

Answer (score 0):

i got also an another solution 
and it works well

```
$(this).Ajax_Data("OnePageGrid", "Delete", { Id: CurrantID }, 
{ onsuccess: document.getElementById("tblBlah").deleteRow(RowIndex) },
{ onerror:  alert('there is some thing wrong !!') });
```